# Have the requirements for building a portal changed?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, crafting, portals

The *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* is the [only source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150909224751/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/feats&tablesort=2&tablefilter=create%20portal) I'm aware of for the feat Create Portal (34). The feat is untouched by errata and has as its only prerequisite the feat [Craft Wondrous Item](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#craftWondrousItem) (*PH* 92-3).

But the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* on Building a Portal says

> Any character of at least 17th level can build a *portal* if she knows the Create Portal feat and either the *teleportation circle* or *gate* spell. (61)

As the feat Craft Wondrous Item has as its lone prerequisite *Caster level 3rd*, a wizard can take the feat Craft Wondrous Item then the feat Create Portal as his wizard bonus feat *at level 5*.

Yet he won't be able to create on his own a *portal* until level 17.

This seems like a long time to wait.

While it's *interesting* that a low-level wizard could knock on the archmage's door and offer his *portal*-building skill in exchange for the archmage's spell knowledge (the Wiz5 providing the feat and Wiz17 providing the spell knowledge), unlike [many](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#creatingMagicArmor) [other](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#creatingRods) [magic](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#creatingWands) [items](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#creatingWondrousItems), the *portal* doesn't need the Wiz17 to **expend** the spell [*gate*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gate.htm) or [*teleportation circle*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportationCircle.htm) during the the *portal*'s creation. Seriously, in the hypothetical scenario, the archmage **supervises** *portal* creation, expending zero resources except time (and, perhaps, patience at being stuck hanging around a Wiz5).

#### Here're the questions.

1. The *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* is from 2001. The game is in its infancy. Should the quoted text be read as *guidelines*, as the feat Create Portal has no further prerequisites? That is, should anyone with the *capacity* to cast either the spell *gate* or the spell *teleportation circle* be permitted to use the feat Create Portal? (Perhaps cribbing from an arcane *scroll of teleportation circle* (9th-level spell at caster level 17) (*DMG* 241) (4,825 gp; 0 lbs.) is sufficient?)

   Alternatively, is there a *reason* to restrict creating *portals* to characters level 17 and higher but to give characters the ability to consider for 12 levels their poor and probably pointless choices?
2. Was the portal creation process updated or expanded upon in later texts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The feat Create Portal was deleted by the *Player's Guide to Faerûn*, but prerequisites for creating *portals* remain otherwise unchanged

The *Player's Guide to Faerûn* on Changes to Feats from the Campaign Setting says

> In addition to overhauling the regional feat system, this chapter also introduces a small number of changes to other feats from the *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*. Most of these alterations are minor changes to the wording for clarity, but some of the key changes include the following.…

> **Create Portal:**  *Portals* are now considered wondrous items and are built with the Craft Wondrous Item feat. The new *Portal* Master feat makes it easier for a character to build a *portal*. (42)

(The *Player's Guide* likewise describes the feat Portal Master (42).)

So by removing the feat Create Portal, any ol' caster with access (somehow) to the [correct](https://web.archive.org/web/20161225075701/http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org:80/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsFtoG.html#gate) [spells](https://web.archive.org/web/20161225074952/http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org:80/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsTtoZ.html#teleportation-circle) and [a feat with a prerequisite of caster level 3rd](https://web.archive.org/web/20170224124905/http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org:80/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsAll.html#craft-wondrous-item) can opt to create a *portal*.

Thus, without *portals* requiring their own specific feat to create and the large number of high-level casters on Toril and the utility value of the feat Craft Wondrous Item, the ubiquity of Faerûnian *portals* becomes a bit more understandable, despite *portals* themselves still possessing sort-of silly yet otherwise untouched prerequisites for creation.

So you know, *Underdark* has a few more portal qualities (52-3), *Expedition to Undermountain* describes Halaster’s drifting *portals* (218), and *Power of Faerûn* and *Dungeon* #92 describe a *portal* that emits deadly flying needles (152) and coral *portals* (79), but these latter two designs are largely specific to the location and group associated with them, respectively.

---

***Note:** This revision means that the DM must make minor adjustments to the prerequisites of the item creation feat [Create Moving* Portal *](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101074329/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/pg/20030611a) and the epic feat [Create Time* Portal](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101074237/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/pg/20030416b).

Answer (score 4):

### Answer to Question #1

*Yes*, there are rules supporting multiple people during magic item creation. SRD states:

> It is possible for more than one character to cooperate in the creation of an item, with each participant providing one or more of the prerequisites. In some cases, cooperation may even be necessary.
>
> If two or more characters cooperate to create an item, they must agree among themselves who will be considered the creator for the purpose of determinations where the creator’s level must be known. The character designated as the creator pays the XP required to make the item.

### Answer to Question #2

*No*, there are no other RAW supporting Portal Creation outside of the texts you have already quoted. As I can't prove a negative - this may seem as opinion. There may be some 3rd party resources that I am unaware of, and some Homebrew resources floating around the internet somewhere.

### Suggestion

Make a Magic Door (portal) as a spell trigger wondrous item using [Teleport](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleport.htm) / [Greater Teleport](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportGreater.htm) with the other Magic Door linked. There will need to possibly be some creative license by the DM. It could be some "fun" roleplaying allowing a chance of failure using the standard Teleport spell. But having the DM state that the two "doors" linked teleporting back and forth to each other shouldn't be too far a stretch of the imagination. It is not gamebreaking by any method. And using certain spell triggers could also help prevent others from freely using the Magic Door. Also, having familiarity limitations as prescribed from the two Teleport spells can also prevent the Average Joe from utilizing the Magic Door.

The only reason Create Portal requires 17th level, is due to [Teleportation Circle](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportationCircle.htm) being a 9th level spell.

Comment: I *still* don't understand what the spells *teleportation circle* or *gate* have to do with creating a *portal* when neither needs to be cast to create a *portal*. But that's not on you--I'm just kvetching.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Well, Teleportation Circle is only for one location and cannot be changed. And Gate is only for one plane. That is the only thing I can think of.