# What planar traits prevail in extradimensional spaces?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, planes, time

The great wizard Mordenkainen creates himself a [fast-time](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/planes.htm#time) demiplane, and makes 1 day in the demiplane take 1 minute on the Prime Material Plane. He invites his friends over to a housewarming party. Because he forgot to buy any furniture or food, he casts his patented [magnificent mansion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesMagnificentMansion.htm) spell.

> You conjure up an extradimensional dwelling that has a single entrance on the plane from which the spell was cast. ... Since the place can be entered only through its special portal, outside conditions do not affect the mansion, nor do conditions inside it pass to the plane beyond.

After a whole day of partying, his guests leave the *mansion*, and *plane shift* to the Prime Material Plane. **But how much time has passed there?** 1 minute, because of the demiplane's fast time, or 1 day, because the *mansion* is extradimensional and not inside the demiplane?

Is the answer the same for other extradimensional spaces like [rope trick](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/ropeTrick.htm) or a [portable hole](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#portableHole) even though they lack the "outside conditions" text?

Comment: Does it help to know that [extradimensional spaces are themselves demiplanes](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37842/8610)?

Comment: It does, but I don't think it's quite the same question. Unless you are suggesting that a creature could sit inside an open *portable hole* and explore the most hazardous planes without harm by dragging themselves around on artificial appendages as some sort of nautilus - in which case I'd love exactly that as an answer anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The traits of the plane you're on affect you; the traits of the plane you *left* don't matter on that new plane

Any extradimensional space is also its own demiplane. The *Dungeon Master's Guide* on [Demiplanes](http://dndsrd.net/planes.html#what-are-demiplanes) says

> This catch-all category covers all extradimensional spaces that function like planes but have measurable size and limited access. Other kinds of planes are theoretically infinite in size, but a demiplane might be only a few hundred feet across. Access to demiplanes may be limited to particular locations (such as a fixed gateway) or particular situations (such as a time of year or a weather condition). Some demiplanes are created by powerful magic, some naturally evolve, and some appear according to the will of the deities.
>
> In the *D&D* cosmology, also known as the [Great Wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Great_Wheel_cosmology), the
>   planes are connected in a specific fashion, as depicted in the diagram on page 153. (The diagram does not show demiplanes, because the location and even the existence of these extradimensional spaces is constantly changing.) (147)

That means when a creature travels from wherever it is *to* an extradimensional space, the creature is literally *traveling to another plane*. The plane the creature *was* on? The creature's not *on* that plane anymore. And the plane the creature's *now* on? The creature is *only* there. It's very rare when the plane that was traveled *from* affects the plane that's traveled *to* unless the creature somehow brings that effect with it or whatever.

> #### A whatever: *portal* seepage
>
> *Underdark* on *Portal* Seepage says
>
> > A newly created *portal* functions well and sustains a solid barrier between its origin and destination points. As centuries or millennia pass, however, a *portal* can decay or malfunction…. In addition to malfunctions, *portal* seepage may occur in older *portals*. When this phenomenon occurs, qualities of the *portal*’s destination side start to soak into its origin side.
> >
> > When a *portal* seeps, the planar traits described in Chapter 5 in the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* begin to affect the surrounding area. The rate can vary, but the area covered by the seepage averages a 5-foot radius around the *portal* per 100 years of age. (53)
>
> However, because [creating a *portal* is *so* onerous](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53453/8610), the idea of creating a *portal* on a plane possessing a fast time trait then awaiting the *portal*'s decay so that the *portal*'s destination side can benefit from the fast time trait is an exploit that's exclusive to high-level characters. Further, it's unreliable, and it carries with it a significant risk of getting hit by hurled dice.

So when a wizard casts [*rope trick*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#rope-trick) and climbs up the rope, casts *Mordenkainen's [magnificent mansion](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#mages-magnificent-mansion)* and steps through the door, or—while wearing a [*necklace of adaptation*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#necklace-of-adaptation)—climbs into his well-appointed [*portable hole*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#portable-hole) for a nap, that wizard's traveled to a different plane, and the planar traits of the plane the wizard departed don't have any affect on the (maybe very small demi)plane the wizard's on now, which has its own separate set of planar traits.

#### Notes

- It's still sometimes possible for a joker to mess with the wizard's *method* of transportation to the new plane *from* the wizard's origin plane by, for example, by [dispelling the *trick*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31524/8610), by [dispelling the *mansion*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55580/8610), or, because the owner for some reason left it sitting around, by dispelling the *hole* (rendering it inert for a 1d4 rounds) or by simply lighting the *hole* on fire.
- Unless a plane *says* it's otherwise *not* normal (like the limited air supply present in the extradimensional space of a [*bag of holding*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#bag-of-holding), for instance), this DM assumes the plane's traits *are* normal. Thus, for example, the demiplane created by the spell *Mordenkainen's magnificent mansion* has normal gravity, time, and magic traits (*DMG* 147, 148, and 149, respectively)… which are, as described above, unaffected by the planar traits of the plane on which the *mansion*'s entrance is created.
- Also, because it's *important*, this DM tries to limit ambiguity by applying the rules for *portals* to extradimensional spaces: A creature's either *on* a plane or on a *different* plane and *never* on *both* planes *simultaneously*. (And, yes, the spell *[blink](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#blink)* sort of says *Hi!* and I don't care.) For example, stuff comes to the top of a *bag of holding* as the holder desires so *reaching in* isn't a thing, and upending a *bag* spills its contents, and a creature climbs into a *portable hole* to fetch stuff from it. In my campaigns, this prevents, for example, one PC from carrying another PC around in *bag of holding* with just the other PC's head sticking out of the *bag* while the buddy explores a fast-time trait plane just so the other PC can see if his head and his body age at different rates.

Comment: We usually have unspecified traits of demiplanes copy those of the plane they were created on, which prevents some of the exploits your ruling allows but creates its own set of problems.  In any case 'you get the (unspecified) traits of your created area' is the right answer, +1

Comment: @thedarkwanderer That's *also* a totally fair ruling, and one that I hadn't even considered. What do you do with things like *bags of holding* and such? Do those also mimic the traits of the plane on which the magic item is opened? (That seems like it might be open to *ruthless* exploitation under the right circumstances—for instance, plopping a dragon equipped with a *necklace of adaptation* and a *ring of sustenance* into a *portable hole* while on a fast-time trait plane then toting around the *hole* for a few months to [force-age](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79564/8610) the dragon!)

Comment: It mimics the traits of the plane it was created on (like everything else).  Generic bags of holding are from the Material Plane, generally, but you could create one or buy one with specific traits if you wanted to and the GM let you.  Plopping the dragon in your bag of holding and waiting a few months isn't too much different than just plane shifting it to wherever the bag was made and then waiting.  Fast time is a huge problem, but the extradimensional spaces copying thing doesn't make it too much worse.